# Beside Barchart with ggplot()-function is not working in R-studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a barchart with two or multiple values (bars) for a category on the x-axis. However, it is not working with the ggplot()-function. It does not show the bars beside one another. I think the values overlay. However, I put the position ="dodge".

I have two datasets, one for the year 2020, and one for the year 2019, with the same categories and I'd like to plot them together in one barchart with two bars for each category.

I used this code:
`tgc_combi = rbind(tgc20, tgc19)` #First, I combined the two datasets, then I tried to plot them:

```
ggplot(tgc_combi, aes(x=Category, y=Visitors)) + 
  ggtitle("Number of visitors in each category")+xlab("Category")+ylab("Visitor numbers") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Visitors-se, ymax=Visitors+se),
                width=.2,                   
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Maybe it is because the categories are called the same in tgc20 and in tgc19?
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You need to set `aes(fill = [some_column])` or `group = [some_column]` for bar grouping to take effect.

Comment: Thank you @jdobres . I tried both, however, it is still overlaying my bars. I have 8 categories, so it should plot 16 bars, however, it only plots 8 bars with two error bars in each bar. Any other ideas? Do I maybe need to merge my two datasets (tgc20 and tgc19) in a different way?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: tgc20 and tgc19 look like this:
Category   N Visitors        
1    BEHAV  83   
2    BIRTH  27   
3     CONS  16   
4      EDU  19   
5       GE 106   
6   HEALTH  15   
7      NEW   4   
8      OUT   2   
when I merge with rbind(), it looks like this:
   Category   N Visitors      
1     BEHAV  83  
2     BIRTH  27  
3      CONS  16  
4       EDU  19  
5        GE 106  
6    HEALTH  15  
7       NEW   4  
8      OUT   12
9     BEHAV  53  
10    BIRTH  13  
11     CONS   3  
12      EDU   4   
13       GE  39   
14   HEALTH   7  
15      NEW   3   
16      OUT  11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `group` in your `aes`. Without `group` there is no way to distinguish the data from 2019 and 2020. Also, if you had lighter color bars you would have noticed darker shade for the lower values, which happens to be for 2020 values in your example.
I am assuming that you have calculated `se`, and have them in your dataframe.

The following code

```
c <- c("BEHAV", "BIRTH", "CONS", "EDU", "GE", "HEALTH", "NEW", "OUT")
v <- c(83, 27, 16, 19, 106, 15, 4, 12)
se1 <- c(8.8,3.3,0.9,2.1,5.6,1.1,0.5,2.8)
y <- c(rep(2019,8))               
tgc19 <- data.frame(Category=c, Visitors=v, Year=y, se=se1)
v2 <- c(53, 13, 3, 4, 39, 7, 3, 11)
se2 <- c(9.8,2.3,1.9,1.5,4.6,0.6,1.1,2.2)
y2 <- c(rep(2020,8))               
tgc20 <- data.frame(Category=c, Visitors=v2, Year=y2, se=se2)

tgc_combi <- rbind(tgc20,tgc19)
tgc_combi$Category <- factor(tgc_combi$Category, levels=c)
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
limits <- aes(ymax = Visitors + se,
              ymin = Visitors - se)

ggplot(tgc_combi, aes(x=Category, y=Visitors, group=Year, fill=Year, color=Year)) + 
  labs( title="Number of visitors in each category", x = "Category", y= "Visitor numbers") +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=unique(tgc_combi$Category)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.2, color=c("red"))
```

gives the following output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you @YBS ! How can I add the errorbars to both years)? I used this code: 
`ggplot(tgc_combi, aes(x=Category, y=Visitors, group=Year, fill=Year, color=Year)) + 
  labs( title="Number of visitors in each category", x = "Category", y= "Visitor numbers") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=unique(tgc_combi$Category)+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=c(v$Engagement-se,v2$Engagement-se), ymax=c(v$Engagement+se,v2$Engagement+se),
                width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)))`

Comment: Please see the updated code and output.  Your code looks like it should work.