# How to plot multiple variables with means as y values for multiple groups in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, histogram

I have already researched the webs on how to do this but nothing has worked - there is an element missing always. I am trying to plot histogram for mean fish condition (y axis) for males and females(colour/legend) for each age group(x axis). What complicates it more is that I have multiple sites so I am not sure how to go about it. I have attached what is kind of close to what I had like to [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73gCW.png)(note how a factor is missing-sites). There is a lot of code I have tried but I will provide a sample below. My data is saved as a csv with different columns that have sex, site, fish condition, etc.
F8 is the csv sheet that has multiple sites from one year
K is the fish condition column that I want means calculated for

```
gender.mean <- t(tapply(F8$K,
                        list(F8$Age1, F8$Sex), mean))
```

^I am not sure how to factor in the site as well.
I plotted this (code below) which gives me mean condition for both males and females for each age group but its all of sites combined.

```
barplot(gender.mean, col=c("darkblue","red"), beside=TRUE, legend=c("F","M"))
```

^for some reason, the x axis line (not numbers) is missing though and the legend is on top of the bars?

In addition, I had like the bars to have standard error bars but

```
geom_errorbar( aes(x=name, ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd), width=0.4, colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=1.3)
```

the above code has not worked.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions should be reproducible. Please don’t use images of code or data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`. This will make it easier for someone to help.

Comment: The answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981249/beside-barchart-with-ggplot-function-is-not-working-in-r-studio